# Laptop goes to sleep when lid is closed and disconnected from power

Tags: sleep, power, macbook-pro, external-display, lid

I am trying to work with my computer (Macbook Pro) attached to an external monitor, while the lid is closed.  I can work on it when the laptop is connected to power, but when I disconnect it from the power the computer goes into a sleep state and I can’t see anything on the external screen.

Does anybody have any suggestion in how to solve this?

Comment: You title talks about closing the lid, yet the body is talking about removing Power. Also, removing power form the laptop shouldn't put it into an idle state..  So I'm confused...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes maybe I should rephrase that. I have the problem when I close the lid and I remove it from the power. I don't have the problem when I have either or.

Comment: Ok, please update your question (and its title) with this clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is expected behavior:](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834)

> Requirements for closed-display mode
>
> - Power adapter
> - External keyboard, mouse, or trackpad
> - External display

There’s probably nothing you can do when using OS X.